# Resampling by group ends up returning Type error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, ohlc

I have a dataframe like this :

```
          Symbol                Time   Open   High    Low  Close  Volume    LOD    10MA     20MA  Sessions
    0       AEHR 2021-08-20 09:31:00   5.52   5.52   5.52   5.52    3383   5.52     NaN      NaN         1
    1       AEHR 2021-08-20 09:32:00   5.57   5.57   5.57   5.57    1012   5.52     NaN      NaN         1
    2       AEHR 2021-08-20 09:35:00   5.56   5.56   5.56   5.56    4119   5.52     NaN      NaN         1
    60864     ZI 2021-09-10 15:58:00  63.07  63.12  63.07  63.10   16650  62.84  63.105  63.1420       165
    60865     ZI 2021-09-10 15:59:00  63.09  63.12  63.06  63.11   25775  62.84  63.108  63.1270       165
    60866     ZI 2021-09-10 16:00:00  63.11  63.17  63.11  63.17   28578  62.84  63.115  63.1200       165
```

I have already added a masking column called `Sessions`. I would like to resample current `1Min` into `60Min` for each unique `Sessions`

Don't care what happens to `Volume`    `LOD`    `10MA`     `20MA`, will be dropping those.  Also, this is the sample set, the final dataset will have 350million rows so efficiency is of concern.

```
df = df.groupby("Sessions").resample('60Min', label='right', on='Time')
```

Returns

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby' object has no attribute 'grouper'
```

---

My understanding is that .resample() returns this:

- `Time` e.g `10:00:00` will include data from `9:30:00 - 10:00:00` (since market only opens at 9:30, all other time will be for the full hour). `11:00:00` will include data from `10:01:00 - 11:00:00` etc
- `Open` should be the first value of the series for each `Sessions`
- `High` should be the `max()` value for each `Sessions`
- `Low`  should be the `min()` value for each `Sessions`
- `Close` should be the last value of the series for each `Sessions`

Comment: Is the date and time column in date format? Please use the following code to convert it. `df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` And resampling can only summarize the time, the calculation of each value must be specified separately. `df.groupby("Sessions").resample('60min', label='right',on='Time').agg({'Open':'first','High':'max','Low':'min','Close':'last'})`

Comment: thanks @r-beginners. Im having 2 issues: 1. The resample is ending a `17:00:00` row despite the last row being `16:00:00`. 2. `'Sessions' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.` Can I convert the index to a column?

Comment: For the first, you can use label='left' to make it based on the start date, and for the second, you can just reset index and then index the target column.